# Django join tables with two FK fields backwards

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I cannot figure out this queryset's filter settings in Django:

```
class City(models.Model):
  cityname= models.CharField()

class Doctor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  primarycity = models.ForeignKey(City)
  secondarycity = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

I want to query:
All cities (primary or secondary) that have a doctor with the name of 'Smith'

The obvious does not work for me:

```
list = City.objects.filter(doctor__name='Smith')
```

This will only provide me with a list of primary cities with 'Smith'. I need Django to follow both FK fields (city and secondarycity)

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify `related_name` argument. Something like

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    primarycity = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='primary_doc')
    secondarycity = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='secondary_doc')
```

After that you can use Q objects:

```
list = City.objects.filter(Q(primary_doc__name='Smith') | Q(secondary_doc__name='Smith'))
```

Comment: related_name is not a must

Comment: I just tried it out and solves my issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is **no query** that can only be done when related_name is set. The default value is always fine.

Comment: @doniyor even when one model has two relations to the another model? What names would then have been set? doctor_set1 and doctor_set2?